# Is it possible to run Python code in Sublime Text3 as I code along?

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext3, real-time

I think I had seen a video somewhere on YouTube earlier which showed someone coding Python 3 on Sublime Text3. It worked as follows:

He types:

```
x=10
y=x+5
```

And automatically both of these statements get enclosed in a block and an output gets printed in the console as follows:

```
x=10
y=15
```

Then he continues coding another line which gets enclosed in a separate block.

```
z=x+y
```

And the execution seems to continue the state from last time because the output shows:

```
z=25
```

These weren't the exact statements but I'm trying to communicate the idea over here. I cannot find that video or any information related to this after a lot of searching. Perhaps I'm using wrong keywords.

Is there a way to run Python3 code in Sublime Text3 in real time (perhaps they're using a built-in terminal that retains state while coding a single program?).

Comment: You could, for example execute your code on save

Comment: Something like [SublimeREPL](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeREPL) could probably do this. You could also install [Terminus](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Terminus) and run python in there.

Comment: @user8408080 do you mean building manually every time I save? That would cause all the steps to be run right from the beginning until the last line I typed. The whole idea is to save time while typing by getting it validated as you type it.

Comment: @OdatNurd I searched through repl but didn't find something that resembles this feature. Perhaps if I can know the name of this feature then I could Google better for it. Currently I'm searching for it as "running in real time repl" or, "execute as you code repl" with no luck.

Comment: Literally, REPL means `Read`, `Evaluate`, `Print`, `Loop`; as you enter the lines, they execute. When you run `python` at a command prompt, this is the mode it goes into by default. The package I referenced above adds the ability to do that directly in a Sublime tab, and the Terminus package would open a teminal in a tab where you could run `python` and do the same thing.

Comment: @OdatNurd sounds great! Okay let me give this a try.